# Overwrite TikZ auto placement of weights in graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, arrows, automation, graphs

So I have the following graph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{vertex}=[draw=black!25,shape=circle,fill=black!25, edge=black!25,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{edge} = [draw,thick,-]
\tikzstyle{arrow} =[draw,thick,->]
\tikzstyle{weight} = [font=\scriptsize]

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,auto,swap]
\foreach \pos /\name in {{(0,0)}/1,{(1,1)}/3,{(0,2)}/2,{(2,2)}/4,{(2,1)}/5}
   \node[vertex](\name) at \pos{$\name$};
\foreach \source /\dest /\weight in {1/3/1,1/5/2,2/1/5,3/2/2,3/5/3,4/2/8,5/2/7,5/4/5} 
   \path[arrow] (\source) -- node[weight] {$\weight$} (\dest);
\foreach \source /\dest /\weight in {1/3/1} place \weight above of=\path[arrow];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in the following graph:

[image]

As you can see, the auto-placement of the weights isn't ideal. The weight of the arrow from 1 to 3 and the weight of the arrow from 3 to 2 would be placed better above and below their arrows, respectively. Is there any way to "overwrite" the auto-placement, without having to manually define all weight positions? Ie: can I tell a specific weight to be placed in an other position?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Nttell, welcome to the site! Could you please turn your code snippet into a complete minimal example document, starting from `\documentclass`? Answering questions is fun, completing code to make it compilable is not.

Comment: No problem, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create two `foreach` loops, and only specify the position for the ones you want to change:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{vertex}=[draw=black!25,shape=circle,fill=black!25, edge=black!25,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{edge} = [draw,thick,-]
\tikzstyle{arrow} =[draw,thick,->]
\tikzstyle{weight} = [font=\scriptsize]

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,auto,swap]
    \foreach \pos /\name in {{(0,0)}/1,{(1,1)}/3,{(0,2)}/2,{(2,2)}/4,{(2,1)}/5}
        \node[vertex](\name) at \pos{$\name$};
    \foreach \source /\dest /\weight in {1/5/2,2/1/5,3/5/3,4/2/8,5/2/7,5/4/5} 
        \path[arrow] (\source) -- node[weight] {$\weight$} (\dest);
    \foreach \source /\dest /\weight/\pos in {1/3/1/{above left}, 3/2/2/{below left}} 
        \path[arrow] (\source) -- node[weight, \pos] {$\weight$} (\dest);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: weighted graph]

Answer (score 3):

You can put the weights in the middle of the edge, within a white background (Not exactly a response to your question):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{vertex}=[draw=black!25,shape=circle,fill=black!25, edge=black!25,minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{edge} = [draw,thick,-]
\tikzstyle{arrow} =[draw,thick,->]
\tikzstyle{weight} = [draw=none,fill=white,inner sep=1pt,font=\scriptsize]

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,swap]
\foreach \pos /\name in {{(0,0)}/1,{(1,1)}/3,{(0,2)}/2,{(2,2)}/4,{(2,1)}/5}
   \node[vertex](\name) at \pos{$\name$};
\foreach \source /\dest /\weight in {1/3/1,1/5/2,2/1/5,3/2/2,3/5/3,4/2/8,5/2/7,5/4/5} 
   \path[arrow] (\source) -- node[weight] {$\weight$} (\dest);
\foreach \source /\dest /\weight in {1/3/1} place \weight above of=\path[arrow];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pdflatex output]